# get token expiration time after using GoolgeAuth.getAccessToken

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth

I am using GoogleAuth.getAccessToken() to fetch accessToken for google API request.

```
  const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');

  const retailAuth = new GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: './credential.json',
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
  });

  const newToken = await retailAuth.getAccessToken();
```

I want to store and reuse it before it is expired (using firebase firestore now).

However, the method above only returns a String token without expiration.

How do I know the expiry time of that token and regenerate when it is near expiry.

Comment: Hi updated the answer with typescript now. Can you try it once ?

Comment: If you are getting access_token undefined means it's possible that the credentials have not been obtained yet. The `getAccessToken()` and `getClient()` methods are asynchronous and return a Promise, so you need to wait for them to resolve before accessing the credentials.

Comment: Hi does recent changes in my answer solve your issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the expiry date from the `expiry_date` property of the `Credentials` object returned from `getClient()` method as follows:

Assuming you are using firebase-functions as your cloud functions then you can initialize the admin sdk and save the access token in Firestore and refresh it before it expires. Although here I am generating new access token if the old one is expired, But you can modify the following `getAccessToken()` functions as per your need like generating through refresh-token:

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import {GoogleAuth} from "google-auth-library";

admin.initializeApp();

const firestore = admin.firestore();

const retailAuth = new GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: "./credential.json",
  scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
});

async function getAccessToken() {
  const {credentials} = await retailAuth.getClient();
  const accessToken = credentials.access_token;
  const expiryDate = credentials.expiry_date;

  const tokenRef = firestore.collection("tokens").doc("access_token");
  await tokenRef.set({token: accessToken, expiryDate: expiryDate});

  return accessToken;
}

async function getToken() {
  const tokenRef = firestore.collection("tokens").doc("access_token");
  const tokenDoc = await tokenRef.get();
  const tokenData = tokenDoc.data();
  if (tokenData && tokenData.token && tokenData.expiry_date) {
    const {token, expiryDate} = tokenData;
    const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    if (currentTime < expiryDate) {
      return token;
    }
  }
  const newToken = await getAccessToken();
  return newToken;
}

// Example use
async function main() {
  const accessToken = await getToken();
  console.log("Access token:", accessToken);
}

main();
```

You can also use `refresh_token` to generate a new `access_token`, if it expired for more info go through [this docs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#obtaining-a-new-refresh-token)

Reference : [**`google-auth-library-nodejs`**](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I have tried this before, but the getAccessToken() only returns a String token rather than a obj. 

`  const tokenObj = await retailAuth.getAccessToken();
  const tokenData = {
    access_token: tokenObj.access_token,
    expiry_date: tokenObj.expiry_date,
  };
  console.log('token data', tokenData.access_token, 'expiry', tokenData.expiry_date);
`
and the result is
'token data undefined expiry undefined'

Comment: @RayOvO Hi updated the answer with typescript now. Can you try it once ? expiry_date is present on Credentials object.

Comment: Hi Rohit, thanks for your further help. I am using JavaScript and tried to use the Credentials object as you mentioned, it is supposed to work, because I can see both access_token and expiry_date are available attributes. However, when I try to print it. the access_token gives me undefined and the expiry_date gives 1.

Comment: @RayOvO If you are getting access_token undefined means it's possible that the credentials have not been obtained yet. The `getAccessToken()` and `getClient()` methods are asynchronous and return a Promise, so you need to wait for them to resolve before accessing the credentials.

Comment: Hi Rohit, I was absent from work these days, I have tried to use await RetailAuth.getClient() and then fetch the token, it looks like it is still not defined

Comment: then you must have initialized it incorrectly with `keyFile` you can debug this with wrapping code in try catch and using some console.logs before and after retailAuth.getClient().